# How to convert a binary data frame to a vector?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame such like

```
dat<-data.frame('0'=c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                '1'=c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0),
                '2'=c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1),
                '3'=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0))
dat
  X0 X1 X2 X3
1  1  0  0  0
2  1  0  0  0
3  0  1  0  0
4  0  0  1  0
5  0  1  0  0
6  0  0  0  1
7  0  0  1  0
8  0  0  1  0
```

I wanted to convert it to a vector like `1,1,2,3,2,4,3,3` where the numbers corresponding the column-th with unit `1`. For example, 4 means the col 4th on row number 6th is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
max.col(dat)
# [1] 1 1 2 3 2 4 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can use `apply`

```
apply(dat == 1, 1, which)
#[1] 1 1 2 3 2 4 3 3
```